# Customize upload button as image preview

Tags: jquery, html, css, file-upload

I am using the following code to display an image preview. In the below code the image preview and choose button are separate but I want both them to be the same like in the below image: 
[image]

As shown in the image above, first it shows the add button. Then, once an image is selected, it displays a preview.

Here is the code I used:

**HTML**

```
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" />
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
    {
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

        if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#imagePreview {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Hide the input
2. Attach `.onclick()` to image placeholder
3. Trigger input click manually

HIH

```js
$(function() {
    $("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
    {
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

        if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#imagePreview').click(function(){
  $('#uploadFile').click();
});
```

```css
#imagePreview {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150');
}

#uploadFile{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagePreview" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="placeholder image goes here"></div>
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" />
```

Comment: where at add 'on click' function

Comment: i cant upload file even if i click on placeholder nothing happens

Comment: @sanojlawrence; were you able to use this already, are you still having troubles, what errors do you get when you click on placeholder?

Comment: when i click on place holder nothing happens

Comment: @sanojlawrence are you using the snippet I posted? try this and tell me what the console is saying: `$('#imagePreview').click(function(){console.log($('#uploadFile'));});`

Comment: @sanojlawrence look, if you don't give me something other than *no doest work i have tried*, how can I help you, try the code I gave you in my last comment, post what you are trying now, some error, something

Comment: @Scaramouche I've just found this solution, and I love it, but... I can't make it work. I copied pasted everything from the snippet but... nothing happens. 

$('#imagePreview').click(function(){console.log($('#uploadFile'));}); won't say anything because it won't detect onClick. 
How is going to detect onClick or onChange if it's not defined in the HTML?

Comment: Okay, I've resolved it. 
The jQuery code must be inside of $(document).ready(function(){

But that line won't appear in the snippet DONT KNOW WHY!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<label>` to represent and decorate an `input`.

Here's a simple demo:

```js
$('#file1').on('change', function() {
  var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
  if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

  if (/^image/.test(files[0].type)) { // only image file
    var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

    reader.onloadend = function() { // set image data as background of div
      $('img').attr('src', reader.result).removeClass('default')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#file1 {
  display: none;
}

img {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img.default {
  border: 2px gray dashed;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file1">
<label for="file1">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/plus_alt-256.png" class="default" alt="">
</label>
```

Comment: no error, i can  add image but preview doesnt appear

Comment: If you're using the code above in your HTML, please check every attribute sets correct.